# $QS^0$ isn't a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

I am reading Lewis' paper "Is there a convenient category of spectra?". To prove the main result on the non-existence of such a nice category, he shows that otherwise the unit component of $QS^0= \varinjlim \Omega^n S^n$ would have to be weakly equivalent a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces. So far so good, but it isn't immediately clear to me:

**Q:** *Why can't the unit component of $QS^0$ be a product of Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces?*

This should probably be very easy, given how the paper feels no need to include any justification for it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If $X$ is a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces then the map 
$$ \eta^*\colon \pi_2(X) = [S^2,X]\to[S^3,X]=\pi_3(X) $$ is easily seen to be zero (where $\eta\colon S^3\to S^2$ is the Hopf map).  However, standard calculations give: 
\begin{align*}
 \pi_2(QS^0) & =\pi_2^S(S^0)=\mathbb{Z}/2.\eta^2\\
 \pi_3(QS^0) &= \pi_3^S(S^0)=\mathbb{Z}/24.\nu
\end{align*}
with $\eta^3=12\nu$.  Thus, $\eta^*$ is nonzero in this context.

Comment: Also, the unit component has highly non-trivial Dyer-Lashof operations.

Comment: @PeterMay That's true, but the Dyer-Lashof operations depend on the infinite loop structure, which is not unique.  On $Q_0S^0$ there is at least the additive structure, and the multiplicative structure translated from $Q_1S^0$, and probably infinitely many others.  I don't see a simple argument that there cannot be an exotic infinite loop structure with trivial Dyer-Lashof operations.

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful answer, as well as to Peter May for providing an alternative potentially more conceptual explanation.

Comment: Equivalent, really, to Neil's answer is that the ring structure of the mod 2 cohomology of $Q_0S^0$ doesn't look like the cohomology of a product of Eilenberg MacLane spaces by the time one gets to dimension 4: there is a nonzero 2 dimensional class whose square is zero.